# script runs in jupyter notebook but not vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run this code in Jupyter notebook it runs without any error but when I want to run it in VSCODE I get an error , It works by url and a token ,then I got the Json file and exported it to csv file to open in Excel :

**This is the code ;**

```
import json
import requests
import pandas

url = "url"
headers = {"Cookie":"token"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
print(data)


a=data['tickers'][0]['items'][0]['days'][0]['items']

from copy import deepcopy
import pandas


def cross_join(left, right):
    new_rows = []
    for left_row in left:
        for right_row in right:
            temp_row = deepcopy(left_row)
            for key, value in right_row.items():
                temp_row[key] = value
            new_rows.append(deepcopy(temp_row))
    return new_rows


def flatten_list(data):
    for elem in data:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            yield from flatten_list(elem)
        else:
            yield elem


def json_to_dataframe(data_in):
    def flatten_json(data, prev_heading=''):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            rows = [{}]
            for key, value in data.items():
                rows = cross_join(rows, flatten_json(value, prev_heading + '.' + key))
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            rows = []
            for i in range(len(data)):
                [rows.append(elem) for elem in flatten_list(flatten_json(data[i], prev_heading))]
        else:
            rows = [{prev_heading[1:]: data}]
        return rows

    return pandas.DataFrame(flatten_json(data_in))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    json_data = a
    df = json_to_dataframe(json_data)
    print(df)
```

df.to_excel("output.xlsx")

**This is the Error ;**

```
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 59 df.to_excel("output.xlsx")

-> 2026         formatter.write(

--> 730             writer = ExcelWriter(stringify_path(writer), engine=engine)

---> 18         from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from cmd window in VSCODE.

```
  pip install openpyxl
```